How can I make sure a calculated value is unique within a sharepoint list
I have a list with different columns, those columns at the end output a final column that is calculated concatenating those column values.
I want to make sure that, when someone creates a new item in that list, the new item is not repeated, by making sure the calculated output column is not repeated across the list.
How can I do that within the sharepoint environment?
Thanks

Calculated column cannot do that sadly. Other column types do however allow you to enforce unique values for that specific column.

As @Christoffer mentioned, calculated column does not support such functionality.
There are options how to achieve result, but it depends how many extra steps you are willing to take. Example - create integrated Power Apps form with custom validation on field or in SharePointIntegration - OnSave property that executes before submission action.
